# Log requests from called features in reports

Tags: karate

I have a scenario with a step that calls an scenario from other feature file:

```
* def called_feature = call read('feature1.feature')
```

When I check the html report generated with the "html cucumber report" all requests done into the "feature1.feature" are not displayed into the report.

I was wondering if it would be possible to include these requests as well, just to make the reports more readable and can check easily the test flow in case of a failure.

Thanks a lot and congratulations for this amazing framework!

Comment: they should be. so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks Peter.I was working on an example and I realised that the problem is when you call a scenario throw a javascript function, using the "karate.call()" method

Comment: I'll send the sample project soon.